# Scanning in numbers from a text file and finding the sum,largest number, and product

Tags: c, file

I want to be able to scan in a line of numbers from a text file called numbers.txt and then print the sum, largest number, and product in a text file called statistics.txt.

The numbers in numbers.txt would look like:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Currently, i have found a way to find the sum and largest number of the numbers in the text file separately, as you've noticed i have 2 while loops which is incorrect. However, i do not know how to find both the sum and largest number without 2 individual while loops.Also i do not know how to find out the product of the numbers at all.

Note: the 2 while loops work individually, if i take out either 1 of them, the other 1 works

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, sum = 0, numbers, m;

    FILE *filein, *fileout;
    filein= fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    fileout = fopen("statistics.txt", "w");

    //the sum part
    while(fscanf(filein, "%d", &a) == 1)
    {
        sum += a;
    }
    fprintf(fileout, "Sum = %d \n", sum);



    //the max part
    while(fscanf(filein, "%d", &numbers) > 0)
    {
        if(numbers > m)
        m = numbers;
    }
    fprintf(fileout,"Largest = %d\n", m);

    fclose(filein);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `int m = INT_MIN;`.  `m` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

A single `while` loop can perform multiple calculations at the same time.  For example, you can combine your two loops into one like this

```
while(fscanf(filein, "%d", &a) == 1)
{
    sum += a;      // update the sum

    if ( a > m )   // update the max
       m = a;
}
```

Also note that you need to initialize `m` to INT_MIN.

To compute a product, start with a value of `1` and update with `*=`, similar to what you did for the sum.

Comment: thank you for responding, could you explain to me as to why the product value has to be initialized at 1?and m to 0?

Comment: The initial value of `m` is a little tricky, but the idea is that it has to be less than the actual maximum value. To be absolutely certain that you get it right, you should really set it the first value that you read from the file.  When computing the product, the initial value of the product has to be `1` so that multiplying by the first value in the file results in the product being set to that first value.

Comment: What is int_min and why is that used?

Comment: `INT_MIN` is the smallest number that can fit into a variable of type `int`. It is defined in `<limits.h>`